# Removing a delegate from a composition

Tags: c#

I have this code that is supposed to compose a delegate base on some logic. For some reason I cant remove a delegate from the composition.

For example :

```
delegate void MyDelegate();// This is defined in my delegate handler class where ComposeDelegates is
      void ComposeDelegates()
            {
                MyDelegate c = new MyDelegate(destroy + showPoints);//For example this will call Destroy and Show points;

                c = c - showPoints;// This does nothing. If I do c = c +showpoints it will call showpoints twice.
                c();// This calls the functions asociated with the destroy and showPoints delegates.

            }

void ComposeDelegates()// This works as expected;
    {
       switch(type)
        {
            case BehaviourType.JustDestroy:
                c += destroy;
                break;
            case BehaviourType.DestroyAndShowPoints:
                c = destroy + showPoints;
                break;
            case BehaviourType.ShowPoints:
                c += showPoints;
                break;
        }

        c();  
    }
void AnotherWayToComposeDelegates()// This works as well.
        {
            c = destroy + showPoints;
            //Lets say I want to remove showPoints;
            if (type == BehaviourType.JustDestroy)
            {
                c -= showPoints;
            }
            c();
        }
    }
```

Why does the + work but not the - sign. How can I remove showPoints from c ?

Edit: Is it possible that it is not working because this is a Unity3d project and they are using a old version of .Net. But then again why does it compile with no errors ?

Edit 2 : The problem seems to be in instantiating the delega c with new Mydelegate() for some reason.

Comment: What's your delegate definition? MyDelegate?

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev i edited my answer with the definition.

Comment: @UriPopov - You edited your question, not answer :)

Comment: @UriPopov basically what I'm seeing is that you have a delegate declaration and when you do smth incorrectly in ComposeDelegates(). Are you trying to add two methods to invocation list? I'd recommend you to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev from your link its clear that I can use  -= with delegates. I'm not doing anything wrong it simply does not work for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delegate.Combine and Delegate.Remove static methods:

```
delegate void MyDelegate();// This is defined in my delegate handler class where ComposeDelegates is
  void ComposeDelegates()
        {
            var c = Delegate.Combine(destroy,showPoints);

            c = Delegate.Remove(c ,showPoints);
            c();// This calls the functions asociated with the destroy and showPoints delegates.

        }

void ComposeDelegates()// This works as expected;
{
   switch(type)
    {
        case BehaviourType.JustDestroy:
            c = (MyDelegate)Delegate.Combine(c,destroy);
            break;
        case BehaviourType.DestroyAndShowPoints:
            c = (MyDelegate)Delegate.Combine(destroy,showPoints);        break;
        case BehaviourType.ShowPoints:
            c=  (MyDelegate)Delegate.Combine(c,showPoints);
            break;
    }

    c();  
}
void AnotherWayToComposeDelegates()// This works as well.
    {
        c = (MyDelegate)Delegate.Combine(destroy,showPoints); 
        //Lets say I want to remove showPoints;
        if (type == BehaviourType.JustDestroy)
        {
            c =(MyDelegate) Delegate.Remove(c, showPoints); ;
        }
        c();
    }
}
```

Comment: @UriPopov does it solve your problem? In theory += and -= should also work.

Comment: ComposeDelegates() will not work.

MyDelegate c = new Delegate.Combine(destroy,showPoints); - this line has two issues: 1) "new" 2) Delegate.Combine returns Delegate which cannot be casted to MyDelegate.

Something like this will work:
Delegate c = Delegate.Combine(destroy, showPoints);
c.DynamicInvoke();

Comment: new keyword was placed by mistake. I rectified it.

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev if destroy and showPoints both are of type MyDelegate then Delegate.Combine can casted to MyDelegate. See this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549674/why-does-using-delegate-combine-require-a-cast-but-using-the-operator-doesnt)

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev see also this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31400/NET-Multicast-Delegates)

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to fix your syntax to make your code work.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(); // Delegate declaration - it basically a function signature, nothing else.

public void ComposeDelegates()
{
    MyDelegate c = Destroy; // Creates a delegate
    c += ShowPoints; // add ShowPoints to invocation list
    c -= ShowPoints; // Remove ShowPoints from invocation list
    c.Invoke(); // Calls delegate, i.e. invokes all methods attached to delegate.
}

public void Destroy()
{
}

public void ShowPoints()
{
}
```

ATTEMPT 2:

```
public enum BehaviourType
{
    JustDestroy,
    DestroyAndShowPoints,
    ShowPoints
}

public static class MyDelegatesFactory
{
    public static Action Create(BehaviourType type,
        Action destroy, Action showPoints)
    {
        Action result = null;
        switch(type)
        {
            case BehaviourType.JustDestroy:
                result = destroy;
                break;
            case BehaviourType.DestroyAndShowPoints:
                result = destroy;
                result += showPoints;
                break;
            case BehaviourType.ShowPoints:
                result = showPoints;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code:

```
var myDelegates = MyDelegatesFactory.Create(
    BehaviourType.DestroyAndShowPoints, Destroy, ShowPoints);

if (myDelegates != null)
{
    myDelegates.Invoke();    
}
```

Comment: this works but you see in my case showPoints and destroy are also delegates.

Comment: @UriPopov now it's getting more complex. Can you explain what do you want to be called and in which order?

Comment: Still it's += to add and -= to remove even if you use delegate to assign to another delegate

Comment: @UriPopov, I've updated my answer. I'm still not sure if I understand your problem correctly. To my mind you need to revise your code and make it simpler. IMHO you need to get rid of unnecessary complexity. If I were you, I'd keep only one delegate (if at all) and added all functions I needed to its invocation list.